# AJAX runs but image converted from canvas does not goes to database

Tags: php, ajax, html5-canvas

I am trying to store the canvas context to an image and then store this image to database. While the AJAX request has run and image has been collected, nothing gets stored in database. Secondly, none of the messages among alert, echo etc get displayed. It looks as if php file never executed.
Here is the code.

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" placeholder="Select Image">

<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:4px solid black;hover:"></canvas>
<button id="saveImage">Save my Image</button>
```

JS code

```
document.getElementById("saveImage").addEventListener('click',saveImg,false);
function saveImg(event)
{
  var dataURL= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    console.log(dataURL);

  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "zomato.php",
          data: {imgBase64: dataURL}
        }).done(function( respond )
                 {
                // you will get back the temp file name
                // or "Unable to save this image."
                alert("Jquery AJAX request sent ");
                console.log("file saved");
                });


}
```

PHP code

```
define('upload_dir','uploads/');


    $message="php loaded";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname="zomato";
    mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die('cannot connect to the server'); 
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('database selection problem');
     $img = $_POST['img'];  

        $img=str_replace('data:image/png:base64,','' $img);
        $img=str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

        $fileData = base64_decode($img); 
        $fileName='canvas.png';


        $file = upload_dir . uniqid() . '.png';


        $success = file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);

        print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save this image.';
        alert("file has been put");

        $query = "INSERT INTO user_uploads (content ) ".
        "VALUES ('$fileName')";

        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
```

Comment: " alert("file has been put") " - in your PHP code, alert() is your user define in php function  or else?

Comment: no, that is not user defined. I must have instead used echo "alert()". What else might be the error ?